# Google checkout with magento - no impact on admin

Tags: magento, google-checkout

I have set up a magento project successfully equipped with paypal and google checkout. From sandbox and live credential, I entered all the info like Merchant Key and ID into magento admin. I tried all possible configuration.

Secure Callback URL: yes and no.
Sandbox: yes and no

Now, I can checkout through google fine. Then found that admin orders do not have the orders I made using google. Integration Console says-

> "We encountered an error trying to access your server at
>   [my site]/index.php/googlecheckout/api --
>   the error we got is java.io.IOException: Error 'CLOSED' connecting to
>   url '[my site]/index.php/googlecheckout/api'."

Noticed that /va/log/googlemessage.log and /var/log/payment_googlecheckout.log files are updated with some XML that I dont understand.

Can you guys please help me with what's wrong in my understanding?